# How mobile devices can access PostgreSQL db of Odoo server that is deployed on Google Cloud

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, odoo-9, web-development-server

I'm new to Google Cloud. I need to deploy Odoo server to Google Cloud.
I knew that I need to create ubuntu instance to deploy odoo into it.
Odoo DB is postgreSQL. How mobile devices can connect to this db?

Thank You.